# Using jquery index as json key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jQuery event handler that, when clicked, creates a javascript object based on a list of favorite links:

```
$('#saveFavorites').on('click', function(){
        alert("Got inside saveFavorites");
        var myFavorites = {id:null, favorites:[]}; 
        myFavorites['id']= someNumber;

        $('#favoritesList').find('a').each(function(i){
            console.log(i + ":" + $(this).html());
            myFavorites['favorites'].push({             
                i:$(this).html()
            });     
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myFavorites));
    });
```

The problem is that when I output here:

```
console.log(i + ":" + $(this).html());
```

The output is what I want:

```
0:Test1
1:Test2
```

But when I stringify the object:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myFavorites));
```

my output is "i" instead of the stringified integer it represents.

```
{"id":"11111111","favorites":[{"i":"Test1"},{"i":"Test2"},{"i":"Test3"},{"i":"Test4"}]}
```

I'm assuming the push function thinks that my i is the string "i". Is there a way to accomplish what I need to do?

Comment: Do you need `i` and the array of objects? Wouldn't `i` always be the position in the array if you simply pushed `$(this).html()` instead?

Comment: Not necessarily, What I really need is for the id of the element to be the key in the form of [{id:html}]. I was just trying it with the index "i" for simplicity in testing. Is there a way to push a custom key like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#favoritesList').find('a').each(function(i, val){
     console.log(i + ":" + $(this).html());
     myFavorites['favorites'][i] = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The trick was creating the object before I pushed it:

```
$('#favoritesList').find('a').each(function(i){
    //console.log(i + ":" + $(this).html());
    var obj = {};
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    obj[id] = $(this).html();

    myFavorites['favorites'].push(obj);
});
```